# why is Stack a class while Queue is a Interface?

Tags: java, stack, queue

I think they are very similar...And when do we need to use stack or queue, why not just use ArrayList or LinkedList to replace them?

Comment: You should read a good data structures book.  Briefly: The restrictions can improve performance and increase simplicity of understanding the code.

Comment: Because the designers of Java suck at APIs. Stack **should** have been an interface, so there can be different implementations of stacks. For example an array-list based stack and a linked-list based stack. Instead, they took a shortcut and subclassed Vector to make some sort of franken-stack that exposes a lot of incorrect implementation details of its parent. They made an attempt to correct this by creating a Deque (ie another stack implementation) but just created more confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Stack`, is a Last-In-First-Out stack of objects derived from `Vector`, also a class. `Vector` goes with the "old" set of collections that Java originally shipped with, and derives ultimately from `AbstractCollection`. Of note, there's really one canonical implementation of a `Stack`; `Queue`s and `List`s have *many* well known implementations that can make a substantial performance difference when chosen correctly.

`Queue` on the other hand follows the `Collection` interface from the "new" set of collections that are typically used today, so it follows the interfaces and comes with a variety of implementations.

`Stack`s should be used when you need LIFO semantics, while `Queue`s should be used when you need First-In-First-Out semantics.

`ArrayList` and `LinkedList` store *ordered* collections of things, and don't line up with the use-cases of `Stack` or `Queue` directly. `Stack`s and `Queue`s are in a sense buffers of data, whereas the semantics of a `List` typically make it such that it's a store of data; nothing is stopping you from using a `List` to implement a `Stack` or a `Queue`.

Answer (score 7):

Well, one reason is that there are variants of Queues that it is convenient to be able to swap in, like PriorityQueues. They fulfill the same interface but behave differently. I don't think there is anything like that for Stacks, or at least it isn't used nearly as often.

You would not be able to simulate a Priority Queue using just an ArrayList.

Additionally, regarding your second question, you should probably use a stack or queue when that is what you're using *semantically*. That is, if you are doing something like graph traversal, it helps to be very explicit about the sort of data structure you're using.